# How to create a language selection homepage?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, homepage, multi-language

I have a projects that needs a homepage similar to [this one](http://www.tomford.com/). I know there are many multi-language plugins out there. Here's exactly what I need:

```
  if isHomepage and noLanguageSeleted
     show selection page
  else 
     show the actual page content in the sleeted language.
     show all the links and menus in the selected language.
```

How and with the help of what plugin would you achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: One solution I might think of is having a javascript code check to see if the user has selected a language. If not, show the selected language page on top of the current page. I'm not sure with what plugins this might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absolute best plug in for this is [WordPress Multi Lingual (WPML)](http://wpml.org/). I have used this on multiple sites, it works like a charm!.. and it provides excellent documentation for custom theme builders :)

Are you using a free theme? a paid premium theme? or are you building you own theme?
If you are building your own you need to make sure the theme uses the GetText wrapper on all strings.

This plugin is not free, but it is absolutely worth the price! this plugin saves you allot of hassle. Plus you get unlimited updates.

Comment: If you use the WPML plugin you basically need to point them to the other language URL and they will see your page in that language until they choose another one. You can also choose to include a link to other languages at the bottom of each page at the page/post you are on. In the plugin settings you choose if you want a separate domain for each language or just example.com/en for English and example.com/no for Norwegian. So you could just write a normal WordPress page and link them to the different versions with big buttons. Or make a custom page template :)